# A referential integrity constraint violation occurred - How to get offending property?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lazy-loading

> A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property
>   values that define the referential constraints are not consistent
>   between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.

I am using EF6 without lazy loading. This error generally occurs when I attach an object with a foreign key property modified, without nulling his navigation property.

But now I have a object with so much relationships, so, there are a way to get the exact property that are causing the error?

---

Exception details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was caught
  HResult=-2146233079
  Message=A referential integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that define the referential constraints are not consistent between principal and dependent objects in the relationship.
  Source=EntityFramework
StackTrace:
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshotOfSingleRelationship(RelatedEnd relatedEnd, NavigationProperty n, Object o)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.EntityEntry.TakeSnapshotOfRelationships()
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.Internal.EntityWrapperWithoutRelationships`1.TakeSnapshotOfRelationships(EntityEntry entry)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachSingleObject(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, EntitySet entitySet)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddEntityToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.WalkObjectGraphToIncludeAllRelatedEntities(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.AddGraphToObjectStateManager(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean relationshipAlreadyExists, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.IncludeEntity(IEntityWrapper wrappedEntity, Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.EntityReference`1.Include(Boolean addRelationshipAsUnchanged, Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.DataClasses.RelationshipManager.AddRelatedEntitiesToObjectStateManager(Boolean doAttach)
at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.AttachTo(String entitySetName, Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.<>c__DisplayClassa.<Attach>b__9()
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.ActOnSet(Action action, EntityState newState, Object entity, String methodName)
at System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Attach(Object entity)
at System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1.Attach(TEntity entity)
at My.BLL.MyObjectBLL.Update(Myobject obj) in c:\-------\MyObjectBLL.cs:line 105
at App.Controllers.MyObjectController.Edit(Nullable`1 parent, Nullable`1 codigo more fields...) in c:\...\Controllers\MyObjectController.cs:line 265
```

Comment: What TYPE of exception is being thrown?  Does the Inner Exception have a value?

Comment: The type os exception is System.InvalidOperationException, the ex.Data was 0 length and InnerException is null. StackTrace I will post now.